# Splitting a formula

Tags: equations

What is the best way to split an overlong formula such as the following one to multiple lines:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
P2‘‘ &=& 
\begin{pmatrix}
(1-\cos \alpha) \times x\times x + \cos \alpha (1-\cos \alpha) \times  x\times  y -\sin \alpha \times  z  (1-\cos \alpha) \times x\times z +\sin \alpha \times  y \\
(1-\cos \alpha) \times  x\times y + \sin \alpha \times  z (1-\cos \alpha) \times y\times y + \cos \alpha  (1-\cos \alpha) \times y\times z - \sin \alpha \times  x  \\
(1-\cos \alpha) \times  x\times z - \sin \alpha \times  y (1-\cos \alpha) \times y\times z + \sin \alpha \times  x  (1-\cos \alpha) \times z\times z + \cos \alpha  
 \end{pmatrix} \\ 
&\times & 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p2‘_X \\
  p2‘_Y \\
  p2‘_Z
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image: long formula]

Comment: I recommend using `\cdot` instead of `\times`.

Comment: Is it a cross product with everything else being vectors? Otherwise the expression is not a valid multiplication. And if it is so, can you split them up into individual steps?

Comment: The `align` environment is the preferred replacement for `eqnarray`. (Note when you switch that it requires fewer `&` symbols for alignment.) See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: get rid of the X for times, use . (or nothing) which will reduce the width of your formula by about 25-50%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variation of barbara's idea, but without the added complications. Just use `\hfill` in suitable places in order to shove left or right the entry. To one of them I add a fixed space, to give more room. Also some vertical spacings are used to separate each "cell" from the next.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
P2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
  (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot x\cdot x + \cos\alpha (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot x\cdot y \hfill
\hspace{2.5pc} %%% space added to a wide half line, adjust visually
\\
  \hfill{}-\sin\alpha \cdot z (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot x\cdot z +\sin\alpha \cdot y
\\[1ex]
  (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot x\cdot y + \sin\alpha \cdot z (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot y\cdot y \hfill\\
  \hfill{}+ \cos\alpha (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot y\cdot z - \sin\alpha \cdot x
\\[1ex]
  (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot x\cdot z - \sin\alpha \cdot y (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot y\cdot z \hfill\\
  \hfill{}+ \sin\alpha \cdot x (1-\cos\alpha) \cdot z\cdot z + \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
  p2_X \\[1ex]
  p2_Y \\[1ex]
  p2_Z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is really much better than mine.  i was trying too hard.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is one of those problems where some local redefinitions could be very useful.

I've defined matrices `A` and `p` in the below, and used `\cdot` instead of `\times` (assuming that this doesn't change the meaning drastically- if it does, let me know)

[image: screenshot]

I've also used `align` instead of `eqnarray` as detailed in [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We have the matrix equation
\begin{align}
P2'' &= A \cdot  p
\end{align}
where
\[
A=\begin{pmatrix}
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot x\cdot x + \cos \alpha (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot  x\cdot  y -\sin \alpha \cdot  z  (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot x\cdot z +\sin \alpha \cdot  y \\
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot  x\cdot y + \sin \alpha \cdot  z (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot y\cdot y + \cos \alpha  (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot y\cdot z - \sin \alpha \cdot  x  \\
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot  x\cdot z - \sin \alpha \cdot  y (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot y\cdot z + \sin \alpha \cdot  x  (1-\cos \alpha) \cdot z\cdot z + \cos \alpha  
 \end{pmatrix} 
 \]
 and
 \[
 p=\begin{pmatrix}
  p2‘_X \\
  p2‘_Y \\
  p2‘_Z
 \end{pmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Too complicated formulas are simply too complicated. As my fav teacher says: simplify, simplify, simplify. It is much easier to understand couple simple equations than one very complex one.

Answer (score 7):

here's a different approach.

major changes:

- `eqnarray` is replaced by `align`;
- i've replaced `\times` by `\cdot` as suggested by azetina;
- the multiple lines of the first `pmatrix` have been packed into a `minipage` and within the box, `multlined` from `mathtools` has been used, with alternate "middle" lines shoved left or right as appropriate;
- math has to be specified explicitly within the minipage;
- `multlined` doesn't seem to want to use the entire specified width of the `minipage` so some extra space had to be added to the right-adjusted lines;
  `pmatrix` doesn't like just a single line (the `minipage`), so it was replaced with `\left( ... \right)`;
  `minipage` width was adjusted by experiment, and a small `\vspace` added at the top for better appearance.

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P2 &=
\left(
 {\begin{minipage}{.72\textwidth}
  \vspace{2pt}
  \abovedisplayskip=2pt \abovedisplayshortskip=2pt
  $\begin{multlined}
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot x\cdot x + \cos \alpha (1-\cos \alpha)\\
 \shoveright{\kern8em
  \cdot  x\cdot  y -\sin \alpha \cdot  z  (1-\cos \alpha)
   \cdot x\cdot z +\sin \alpha \cdot  y } \\
 \shoveleft{
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot  x\cdot y + \sin \alpha \cdot  z (1-\cos \alpha) } \\
 \shoveright{\kern8em
  \cdot y\cdot y + \cos \alpha  (1-\cos \alpha)
   \cdot y\cdot z - \sin \alpha \cdot  x } \\
 \shoveleft{
(1-\cos \alpha) \cdot  x\cdot z - \sin \alpha \cdot  y (1-\cos \alpha) } \\
  \kern8em
  \cdot y\cdot z + \sin \alpha \cdot  x  (1-\cos \alpha)
   \cdot z\cdot z + \cos \alpha 
  \end{multlined}$
 \end{minipage}}
\right) \\
&\quad\cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p2_X \\
  p2_Y \\
  p2_Z
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you switch the last two terms in each row of the wide matrix then the long term is on a line by itself (rather than split), which makes the algebra much more readable.

Comment: @EthanBolker -- you're right.  that's what egreg has done, and his answer is better in other ways too.

Answer (score 2):

1. `\begin{small}\begin{eqnarray}...\end{eqnarray}\end{small}`
2. read this:
   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87142/avoid-eqnarray-lars-madsen

Comment: Please note that `small` is *not* a LaTeX environment. Hence, `\begin{small} ... \end{small}` is an error. It should be `{\small ...}`.